# Elastic Search Query not giving the right results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run a query which filters according to date range and should meet either of two criteria.

```
"query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "nested":{
                  "query":{
                     "bool":{
                        "must":[
                           {
                              "range":{
                                 "segment_status.updated_at":{
                                    "from":"2021-08-30",
                                    "to":null,
                                    "include_lower":true,
                                    "include_upper":true,
                                    "boost":1.0
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        ],
           "should":[
                       {
                          "terms":{
                                "segment_status.bo_status":[
                                    2,
                                    3,
                                    4
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                        {
                          "terms":{
                                 "segment_status.fo_status":[
                                    2,
                                    3,
                                    4
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        ],
                        "adjust_pure_negative":false,
                        "boost":1.0
                     }
                     
                     
                  },
                  "path":"segment_status",
                  "ignore_unmapped":false,
                  "score_mode":"avg",
                  "boost":1.0
               }
            }
         ]
      }
  }
```

It's filtering according to the date correctly but I'm getting records that don't match any of the mentioned conditions in should clause.

Comment: Use `bool/filter` instead of `bool/must` or add `minimum_should_match: 1` to make sure that at least one should condition matches

Comment: Minimum should match worked. Thank you!! Just out of curiosity, you're asking me to filter the time condition instead of putting it within a must clause right?

Comment: Yes, if you don't need scoring filter is better